# Sublime text change find results panel

Tags: sublimetext

Somehow my find results started showing up on the bottom panel of sublime text instead of the normal, larger, main panel. i can't seem to figure out how to change it back.

i tried asking google, and looking through the preferences. help!

[image: sublimeproblem]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a button in the `Find in Files` panel that controls whether the find results are displayed in a Buffer or in a Panel. You want that to be set to the `Buffer` setting, so probably you inadvertently changed the setting.

To fix it, open up the `Find in Files` panel and ensure that the appropriate button is pressed. Below is an example based on the standard `Adaptive` theme in Sublime Text; the icon may be different for you if you're using a different theme, but the placement will be the same.

[image: Use Buffer Button Location]

Comment: oh yes! i thought i tried this; and i also thought i needed to have this off ...duh! you are wonderful!

Comment: but how do you open this so-called "find in files" panel?

Comment: @Owyn `Find > Find in Files...` from the menu, the key binding that you see in the menu (differs by platform by default) or right click on the panel chooser (the icon in the bottom left of the window to the left of where the image says `[scraps]` above) and you can also pick it from there.